# Running CentOS Docker Image's bin/bash does not allow for hitting enter key

Tags: configuration, docker

Running a basic docker container based on CentOS by executing /bin/bash shows the login but does not allow to hit enter in the expected way. Hitting enter simply starts a new line instead of executing the input line.

I use `sudo docker run -t mycentos /bin/bash` while also using `sudo docker attach d7043c61fcbe` results in the same situation.

Once I am attached to the container I see `[root@d7043c61fcbe /]#` so I think everything is basically correct.

Docker itself runs on ubuntu and I use a default XFCE terminal to issue my docker commands.

[Update]
Just to give you an illustration what I see and what happens:

1. `docker run -t mycentos /bin/bash`
2. `[root@d7043c61fcbe /]#<cursor>` + hitting L-key and S-key on keyboard
3. `[root@d7043c61fcbe /]#ls<cursor>` + hitting Enter-key on keyboard
4. `[root@d7043c61fcbe /]#ls`
   `<cursor>`

So yo see hitting Enter-key allows typing in a new line instead of the bash actually executing the ls command. This behavior makes the bash useless. The same is true for attaching to the container. Without using the bash its very hard to change the container in order to commit it... .

Again this is a recent Ubuntu installation running on VirtualBox running on a Win7. I am using a recent docker installation.

The rest of docker works flawlessly (start/stop/run container, image creation etc.)

Comment: What happens if you actually run it interactively? `sudo docker run -it centos bash` You may also want to detach so bash doesn't exit when you exit the container.

Comment: Its the same. I added a section "update" illustrating what I do and what I see.

Comment: @MartinKersten your update does not include `-i`

Comment: You are correct that solved it. Can you write a very short answer so I can mark it as the right solution.